# Questions with close votes in Stack Overflow weekly newsletter

Tags: support, vote-to-close, newsletter

One of the questions in the "Top new questions this week" section of today's SO newsletter is [Why is processing a sorted array slower than an unsorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023988/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-slower-than-an-unsorted-array?newsletter=1&nlcode=97716%7c4ba7) which has a couple of close votes for being a duplicate. Does the criteria for putting questions in the newsletter filter out questions with close votes? Were the votes cast after the newsletter was composed?

Comment: It's been viewed 870 times since yesterday, and it received 3 close votes. I think it's not going to be closed, personally, clearly most visitors with voting rights don't agree with the close votes gathered so far.

Comment: And the close votes seem to be based on a sloppy reading of the title (and no reading of the post), it may be accidentally closed by others who vote to close before they read the comments or the post, but in that case, it would surely soon be reopened.

Comment: @DanielFischer I guess I'm guilty, because I cast one of the close votes. But I did glance at the other question, and they seemed to be very similar.

Comment: Similar in a way, but dasblinkenlight expected the search in the sorted array to be faster due to branch prediction, and wondered why it turned out to be slower. So it's a different effect (locality) due to using a boxed type that overshadows branch prediction.

Comment: Ahh, now I see it. They're exactly __opposite__ questions.  I was wondering why the new question wasn't blocked by the duplicate title checker.

Comment: Because the titles are not the same?

Comment: Like I said, "__now__ I see it." I didn't notice the oppositeness when I cast the close vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was obviously a mistake.

On a quick reading "Why is processing a sorted array **slower** than an unsorted array?" looks like a duplicate of "Why is processing a sorted array **faster** than an unsorted array?".  Especially as many of us remember seeing the original question.

This has been sorted out now, and the question is reopened.

Comment: So basically you're saying that if a question is really popular, it's appopriate to put it in the newsletter even if there are close votes, because it's likely that they're erroneous.

Comment: I don't think that is considered. I remember seeing the question and was going to vote to close it, but *just* noticed the difference. Obviously some people didn't.

Comment: So are we talking about the algorithm for populating the newsletter or not? That was the subject of my question, we seem to have gone on a tangent about the particular example I used.

Comment: I believe the newsletter goes by "popularity" alone, and doesn't consider that posts with lots of views and upvotes might have close votes as well.